# Solr accent removal

Tags: search, solr, non-ascii-characters

i have read various threads about how to remove accents during index/query time. The current fieldtype i have come up with looks like the following:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField">     
    <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>     
</fieldType>
```

After having added a couple of test information to index i have checked via `http://localhost:8080/solr/test_core/admin/luke?fl=title`

which kind of tokens have been generated.
For instance a title like "Bayern München" has been tokenized into:

```
<int name="bayern">1</int>
<int name="m">1</int>
<int name="nchen">1</int>
```

Therefore instead of replacing the character by its ascii pendant, it has been interpret as being a delimiter?! Having that kind of index results into that i neither can search for "münchen" nor m?nchen.

Any idea how to fix?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is you are applying `StandardTokenizerFactory` before applying the `ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory`. Instead you should use the `MappingCharFilterFactory` character filter factory first and the the `StandardTokenizerFactory`.

As per the [Solr Reference guide](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Tokenizers) `StandardTokenizerFactory` supports `<ALPHANUM>, <NUM>, <SOUTHEAST_ASIAN>, <IDEOGRAPHIC>, and <HIRAGANA>`. Therefore when you tokenize using `StandardTokenizerFactory` the umlaut characters are lost and your `ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory` is of no use after that.

Your `fieldType` should be like below if you want to go for `StandardTokenizerFactory`.

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField">     
    <analyzer>
            <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>     
</fieldType>
```

The `mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt` should have the mappings for such "special" characters. In Solr this file comes pre-populated by default. For e.g. `ü -> ue`, `ä -> ae`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for answering. However the MappingCharFilterFactory seems not to become applied. I do update the index via post.jar sending a json file with the content to be added to index. As i have replaced the Standardtokenizer by a WhitespaceTokenizerFactory, the strings aren't tokenized upon the accents, but neither become replaced by the content of mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt.

Comment: If you are using WhitespaceTokenizerFactory then you can use ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory. Like the fieldType you have in your question, just replace StandardTokenizerFactory with WhitespaceTokenizerFactory.

Comment: I do have applied to different fieldtypes for title field and content_type field with on the hand having MappingCharFilterFactory and on the other hand the ASCIIFoldingFilter. Both variations still aren't working.

http://localhost:8080/solr/test_core/admin/luke?fl=title,content_type

<int name="Bayern M�nche">1</int>
In content_type field and

<int name="m�nchen">1</int>
for title field (having lowercasefilter)

Comment: I would have guessed, it fails due to updating the index via post.jar, not having an appropriate encoding. Thatswhy i have added the Dfile.encoding param. However haven't fixed the problem.

java -Durl=http://localhost:8080/solr/test_core/update -Dtype=application/json -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar post.jar *.json